# Mysql_install_db cannot find file

Tags: mysql, database, installation

I am trying to use mysql_install_db

I am getting the following error:

> FATAL ERROR: Could not find ./bin/my_print_defaults
>
> If you compiled from source, you need to run 'make install' to
>   copy the software into the correct location ready for operation.
>
> If you are using a binary release, you must either be at the top
>   level of the extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option
>   pointing to that location.

I've tried using

```
    which my_print_defaults
```

It returns:

```
    /usr/local/bin/my_print_defaults
```

So I try the command:

```
    mysql_install_db --base-dir=/usr/local/bin/
```

I still receive the same error, though.

Comment: well did you compile mysql from source?

Comment: Sounds like a broken MySQL install. Which platform are you trying to install on?

Comment: @DanyKhalife Mountain Lion. I'm just not sure what to do. There are so many different suggestions out there. Seems like I'm just digging a hole.

Comment: Going to uninstall a bunch of gems/brews and try to install everything.

Comment: IMHO it's much easier to install the MySQL version packaged for OS X.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Annoyingly, this just means you have to be in the right directory to execute this. Make sure you're in `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/<version>/` before running the script.

Comment: This worked for me when I ran into this issue after installing MariaDB through Homebrew on OS X. I had to run the mysql setup scripts from `/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/<version>/`

Comment: Thank you! Small addition: I had to pass the current directory inside the parameter basedir: mysql_install_db --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.24

Comment: Change to the directory where base MySQL folder, something as `cd /var/tmp/your_mysql_base_folder` then run `scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql`. Of course MySQL user and groups must be added first.

Answer (score 4):

You must run the command:
`# mysql_install_db --basedir=/usr/local`
That is without `bin`. This option must specify a directory path location of the directory `./bin`.

Answer (score 3):

Anyone reading this after installing MySQL with Homebrew may have experienced this issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788381/getting-cant-connect-through-socket-tmp-mysql-when-installing-mysql-on-m

And then found their way here after the final instruction didn't work. I simply ran

```
mysql.server start
```

after reading http://benjsicam.me/blog/how-to-install-mysql-on-mac-os-x-using-homebrew-tutorial

Then it all started working miraculously (seems I just hadn't started it?!).

Comment: links are leading to 404 page

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Brew**, try to run **mysql_install_db** with `--basedir="$(brew --prefix mariadb)"`

Change `mariadb` to `mysql` if you use **mysql**.

Answer (score 1):

For me the fix was to point basedir to the actual mysql directory in the cellar, as shown at install.

eg:

During installation of mysql (using `brew install mysql56`), I was shown this path: `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql56/5.6.27/bin/mysql_install_db...`

I used that to define the basedir like so:

```
mysql_install_db --verbose --user=`whoami` --basedir="/usr/local/Cellar/mysql56/5.6.27" --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

gotta add the path of mysql installation in system path
try: `sudo path=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin`
if you installed mysql in "`/usr/local/mysql`"